# Android 2.2: How to update textviews automatically with a timer?

Tags: android, timer, textview

I have some TextViews in my app that I want updated automatically each 5 seconds. I have a method for refreshing them, but how do I make a timer that runs the method every 5 seconds? Thanks!

Comment: Be careful. You need to update these from within the UI thread. Make sure that your timer fires something that will run within the UI thread or else Android will Force Close on you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provide another solution

```
Handler h=new Handler();
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.setContentView(R.layout.main);
    h.post(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // call your function
            h.postDelayed(this,5000);

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 4):

Look at extending a [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html), it has an onFinish() method you can overwrite to update your TextView, and restart the timer if you wish to make it repeat. You can also bind to onTick() if you only want to update a finite number of times.

Comment: Okay but since i dont want it to end i think a normal timer would be better. Got any code examples with that?

Comment: If you don't want it to end set a very high start value and get it to restart in onFinish anyway!

Answer (score -1):

I tried the Handler solution myself, especially after reading this article on the resource pages: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html. But I wanted to be able to start and stop the timer much like a stopwatch, and after resuming the timer the Handler solution started updating much less regularly - on the emulator about every five seconds. In the end I found a tip on a blog that suggested the solution with an inner class extending AsyncTask. You can make use of the publishProgress()-onProgressUpdate() functionality in AsyncTask. From onProgressUpdate(), you're allowed to make changes "directly" in your UI thread e.g. myTextView.setText(...). This publishes results much more frequently. Here's a super simple implementation of that inner class:

```
private class UpdateTimerLabel extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Integer> {

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... arg0) {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                publishProgress(arg0);
                Log.d(tag, "AsyncTask tries to publish");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }if (1 == 0) break; // Silly but necessary I think

        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        updateTimerTextView(); // Call to method in UI
    }
}
```